# How do I compare code to one another in a console?

Tags: javascript

I am new to learning code, so I do not know what to do. Through my course online I discovered that you can compare text using **==**
So when I put **"yes" == "yes"** the console will say **True**
It's a pretty neat feature, but back on topic.

How can I compare code to one another? For example, I want to compare:

"The file located at \"C:\\Desktop\My Documents\Roster\names.txt\" contains the names on the roster."

To another code, but with it telling me if it's similar or not. How do I do it? I read somewhere about using Escaping Strings, but I don't know where to place them.

I appreciate the help,
Zeke

Comment: Is this purely javascript? What is your workflow? do you have a backend? have you already started in reading the file? I think thats the first thing you should search for rather than comparing.

Comment: I am using Udacity to learn... My console is the one you get when right click on Chrome... I just want to see how the command would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for equality compares data on each side of the operator.

`==` is the loose equality operator.

`===` is the strict equality operator.

They differ in how they respond to arguments.

Example:

The string "9" and the number 9 are evaluated by loose equality operator as true

`"9" == 9 // returns true`

However, the strict equality operator, as its name might suggest, also compares the type of data (string vs. number)

`"9" === 9 // returns false`

More examples and cases can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

For comparing the contents of a file, my suggestion in your case would be to parse the file from .json, so that you can treat it as a JavaScript object. Then you can compare the contents with strings of names.

Comment: I never knew that, Thank You So Much!